# Duda sobre recorrido matriz

Tags: c++, loops, matrices

Tengo una duda sobre como recorrer las filas pares de una matriz, yo lo planteé así:

```
 for(int i=2;i<=get_m();i+2)
```

Mi pregunta es:

En la parte de incremento de la fila se puede hacer `i+2` para ir recorriendo solo las filas pares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Operador de incremento

Recuerda que existe un operador de incremento (++) y tambien un operador de decremento (--), los cuales se encargan de aumentar/disminuir una unidad a la variable sobre la que apliquen.

Es decir, que si tu haces esto:

```
int i = 0;
i++;
```

El valor de `i` sera **1**, pero no es necesario reasignar ese valor a `i`, es decir, es lo mismo como si hicieras:

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1;
```

Por lo tanto en los bucles es comun usar dicho operador, ya que el **incremento se asigna automaticamente a la varible** que se compara en la condición.

---

### Codigo

> En este codigo imprimiremos solo los numeros pares de 0 a 10.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

---

### Explicacion

Si quieres que un bucle se ejecute de a cada elemento par, basta que hagas esto en tu bucle:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i=i+2)
```

O tambien:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i+=2)
```

En tu caso:

```
for(int i=2;i<=get_m();i+2)
```

Lo que haria es sumar `i + 2` pero su resultado no seria asignado a ninguna variable, por lo tanto no recorrería de a 2 en 2.

---

### [Ejemplo en linea](https://tio.run/##HYvBDoMgEETP7Fds0ovaNqE9CvZfyELtJgoGoRfjt1Po5eXNTIa27T4TlXJhT0u2DjWHPUVn1hcA@4SrYd81MXGmG9LHRByGGr49HgCiTayqvEPseJKK9UNWTnx99gcIsSc7jhRyQq2RG/6N83ZRIM76jC7l6FEqAWcpPw)

Answer (score 2):

tambien puedes ponerlo de esta forma abreviada:

```
for(int i=0;i<=get_m();i+=2)
```

El contador empezará desde 0 e ira incrementandose la variable i de 2 en 2